# Multiple select in c3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I'm making graphs using c3.js, so far I've been able to select an option in the graph using the event .onClick but I can't figure out how to make multiple selections in the graph since in the documentation they say that data.onselected is not available yet.

Example of what I want to do : 
I have a graph representing : data1, data2 and data3 , what c3.js allows now is select data1 or data2 or data3 but what I want is select data1 and data2

Any idea how to accomplish that ?
Thank you

Comment: Provide some code, even better a working example

Comment: @Cyril I want to zoom in for the x axis, get the data for different values in the x axis

Comment: @Cyril I just saw your Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/YC3Qt8mJkjNfmsu6mV38?p=preview , what I want to do is select multiple bars , in your case you can only select one bar

Answer (score 2):

You could try the inbuilt c3 functionality, used in the chart data declaration:

```
    selection: {
        enabled: true,
        multiple: true,
    }
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-selection-multiple

The only problem is c3 doesn't do an awful lot visually to differentiate selected from unselected as a default, so some css might help:

```
._selected_ : {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.c3-shape:not(._selected_) {
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/890/